# Preventing webkitMovementX is deprecated error?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am developing a webpage using JSAPI for ArcGIS server. I keep on getting this error on console :

> 'webkitMovementX' is deprecated. Please use 'movementX' instead

what dose this error message mean, and is there a way to prevent the error?

I am calling map services of ArcGIS 10.3 server and this is what I reference for code:

> rel="stylesheet"
>   href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/dijit/themes/nihilo/nihilo.css"
>
> rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/esri/css/esri.css"
>
> rel="stylesheet" href="inc/layout.css"
>
> script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/"

I am using Chrome Version 45.0.2454.101 m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for being pedantic, but its not actually an error, but rather just a warning being logged into the console.

```
console.warn('hello') // different than an uncaught exception bubbling up
```

it comes from dojo because of code present in the ArcGIS API for JavaScript itself and can be safely ignored.

Comment: John, as a matter of fact you are more accurate, it is a warning not an error, and the application works just fine with it. BUT are you saying that it is due to ArcGIS API being behind dojo's latest version ?

Comment: not sure exactly.  my best guess is that Dojo is warning about code it sees that wouldn't be compatible with version 2.0 of their own API in the future.

Comment: Well you answer dose explain it. I guess will have to live with it till its handled in next versions of ArcGIS API. Thank you.